# MATLAB File Association in Visual Studio 2015 / TFS

Tags: matlab, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs, file-association

I'm using TFS in Visual Studio 2015, and have a question about MATLAB file associations. For `.m` files, there is no association to MATLAB, as seen here:

[image: Function]

Confusingly, there is an association for `.fig` and `.mat` files, so VS must recognise that MATLAB "exists". If I double click one of these file types, it opens it in MATLAB as it would from within an Explorer window. This is the behaviour I want for `.m` files.

[image: Figure]

**As a minimum, I'd like to have the MATLAB icon for `.m` files so that they're easy to spot in a directory. As an ideal solution, these files would also open in MATLAB (not the VS text editor) from TFS.**

I have tried the "File Extension" option inside of Options > Text Editor, but MATLAB isn't an option for me in the Editor list.

[image: Options]

It's worth noting that my work network is pretty strict on software installs, so the fewer external add-ins the better (ideally none). Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you use TFS source control MATLAB Files? And now you want to integrate MATLAB with VS?

Comment: Where did you see the icon for fig files? In Source Control Explorer or Windows Explorer?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT Source Control Explorer, inside VS. `.mat` files also show the correct icon...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a long time, I've found a reasonable workaround for this.

You can set the "Open With" default for `.m` files, but this seems to open a new instance of MATLAB for every file - not ideal! Suggested by SACn below [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42668062/3978545).

---

A better option is to use Visual Studio's "External Tools".

Go to Tools > External Tools, then as [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76712d27.aspx) shows, create a new tool. Use the following parameters:

```
Title:     Your Title Here
Command:   cmd.exe
Arguments: /c "$(ItemPath)"
```

Tick "Close on exit". This opens the command prompt with the `/c` (terminate after command) flag, and runs the file name of the file which you have open in VS. On Windows systems, this will open the file in an open instance of MATLAB, or launch a new one if none exist.

---

This can be run many ways... Assign a keyboard shortcut, run from the Tools menu, add it to the Toolbar, add it to the context menu.

Now there is one click / key press to launch an open `.m` file as desired. It still lacks the MATLAB file association (and corresponding icon in the file browser) but does the main job!

Answer (score 1):

There's a utility that I often use to fix OS-level association problems with MATLAB-related files - [associateFiles from FEX](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/51165-matlab-file-association-fix).

You should probably call it with `associateFiles('deleteadd','.m')`, which would generate a registry file named `MatlabFileAssocFix.reg` that has the following contents (obviously the MATLAB path is generated according to your system):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;FIXES MATLAB FILE ASSOCIATIONS

;REMOVES M FILE ASSOCIATIONS

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.m]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MATLAB.m.9.1.0]

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.m]

;ADD SHELL OPEN

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\MATLAB.exe\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\D\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2016b\\bin\\win64\\MATLAB.exe\" \"%1\""

;ADD M FILE ASSOCIATIONS

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.m]
@="MATLAB.m.9.1.0"
"Content Type"="text/plain"
"PerceivedType"="Text"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.m\OpenWithProgids]
"MATLAB.m.9.1.0"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.m\PersistentHandler]
@="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.m\Versions\MATLAB.m.9.1.0]
"FileVersionMS"=dword:00090001
"FileVersionLS"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MATLAB.m.9.1.0]
@="MATLAB Code"
"FriendlyTypeName"="@C:\\D\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2016b\\bin\\win64\\matlab.exe,-58"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MATLAB.m.9.1.0\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\D\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2016b\\bin\\win64\\m.ico,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MATLAB.m.9.1.0\Shell\Open]
@="Open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MATLAB.m.9.1.0\Shell\Open\command]
@="\"C:\\D\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2016b\\bin\\win64\\matlab.exe\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MATLAB.m.9.1.0\Shell\Open\ddeexec]
@="uiopen('%1',1)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MATLAB.m.9.1.0\Shell\Open\ddeexec\application]
@="ShellVerbs.Matlab.9.1.0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MATLAB.m.9.1.0\Shell\Open\ddeexec\topic]
@="system"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MATLAB.m.9.1.0\Shell\Run]
@="Run"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MATLAB.m.9.1.0\Shell\Run\command]
@="\"C:\\D\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2016b\\bin\\win64\\matlab.exe\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MATLAB.m.9.1.0\Shell\Run\ddeexec]
@="run('%1')"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MATLAB.m.9.1.0\Shell\Run\ddeexec\application]
@="ShellVerbs.Matlab.9.1.0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MATLAB.m.9.1.0\Shell\Run\ddeexec\topic]
@="system"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.m\OpenWithProgids]
"m_auto_file"=hex(0):
"MATLAB.m.9.1.0"=hex(0):

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.m\OpenWithList]
"a"="MATLAB.exe"
"MRUList"="a"
```

When you import this file, it deletes whichever association exists for `.m` and associates it with MATLAB.

I don't know if this is applicable to your problem, but I thought it should be mentioned.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't fix my problem, but thanks for the link - it seems like a useful function to keep in mind!

Answer (score 0):

Be advised: MATLAB is written in Java and not based on NET or Visual Studio extensions so if we're trying to open MATLAB Editor as plugin this is not a good idea for now.

Now to edit .m files you've to define **new (external) default editor for a file type**.

And if MATLAB license is not present use Notepad++, Sublime and other free editors which support .m file syntax highlighting.

Comment: I understand that, my question is *how* to define a new external default editor, as shown in the image I supplied... A MATLAB license is present, hence why I want to use it!

Comment: Working Solution: First *Open Project with .m files in VS 2015* -> *Press Ctrl+O* -> Choose *All Files*, *Select any .m file*, then **Small DropDown Arrow in Open Button and Click Open With** -> Use *Add* button to add MATLAB to list. Step Two:  In solution explorer *Right Click .m File -> OpenWith -> Now You'll See MATLAB Editor -> Set As Default*

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you want to integrate MATLAB with VS (It seems your issue is not TFS related).

There is not such extension for Visual Studio, but there is a [MatLab extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gimly81.matlab) for [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

=========================================================================

From the comment, it seems you want to use team explore in MATLAB to enable integrated use of Team Foundation Version Control. I'm afraid your requirement can't be achieved at this moment. MATLAB doesn't support team explorer or [TFS MSSCCI Provider](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer20132015M).

I have submitted a user voice at website below, you can vote it:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/18325612-enable-integrated-use-of-team-foundation-version-c.

Comment: That depends what you mean by "integrate"... I don't want to edit files in VS, just use TFS for version control but have it communicate better with MATLAB for opening and displaying `.m` files. I'd already seen the Visual Studio code extension, but I'm not in the market for a different editor...

Comment: Ok, so you want to use team explore in MATLAB to enable integrated use of Team Foundation Version Control, correctly? I'm afraid your requirement can't be achieved at this moment. MATLAB doesn't support team explorer or TFS MSSCCI Provider (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer20132015M). I have submitted a user voice at website below, you can vote it: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/18325612-enable-integrated-use-of-team-foundation-version-c.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, although perhaps you've expanded the scope of what I want. I simply want to be able to open MATLAB directly from VS/TFS, and for my file associations to work... no major integration of one system with the other.

Comment: There is no default way to open MATLAB directly from TFS. But if MATLAB supports Team Explorer or TFS MSSCCI Provider, your requirement will be easily achieved.

Answer (score -1):

OK, here's how I did it:

I have VS code installed, and as such, it creates an association in my default programs like this:

[image]

Then you can just point your VS program at this extension:

[image]

Comment: I'm not using VS Code, as stated in my question title and text, I'm using Visual Studio 2015... I also stated I don't want VS to be the default editor, I want MATLAB to be the default editor and to act like it when files are opened from TFS/VS. Of course MATLAB is already default for `.m` files...